# Is there a way to change the Visual Studio file extensions for modules?

Tags: c++, c++20, visual-studio-2022

I would like to prefer to name module files `.cpp` since I am on my way to start a new project and I try to use modules only.

For this reason I think that my implementation should go into `.cpp` files rather then `.ixx` files.

I develop the project in C++20.

Is there a way to change the modules file extension to something else other than `.ixx` in Visual Studio 2022?

By the way: what is the reason for Visual Studio to only allow the `.ixx` extension for modules? Why not let the developer pick their preferred extension?

Comment: Just as a warning: I tried it with Visual Studio 2022 and VS Code but it looks like both IDEs are not yet ready for C++20 modules. The code competition as well as syntax highlighting for module code is insanely slow and does not work well. If you rely on this features stay away from modules form now, you can also barely find any help for this topic.

Comment: "*Why not let the developer pick their preferred extension?*" Because there has to be a default. And module interface files have to be treated specially by the build system, so it would be nice if they could be identified separately from other files.

Answer (score 2):

Default logic in Visual Studio is tuned to treat files based on extension. So `.ixx` is assumed to be a module interface (i guess *i* in the extension stands for *interface*) and `.cpp` is assumed to be a file for translation unit. However this behavior can be altered from file properties:
[image]

Comment: Setting it to "Compile as C++ Module Code (/interface)" worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a different file extension with MSVC so you can use intellisense in Visual Studio Code, there is actually a work-around.

With the `cl.exe` command, there is an '/interface' option.  You can do like so:

In My cl.exe CommandFile:

```
/interface /Tp UI/ApplicationHost.cpp
/reference ApplicationHost=Build\Debug\ApplicationHost.ifc
UI/WorldEngine.cpp
/link /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS
Build/Debug/pch.obj
```

> **/Interface** - Let's the compiler know there is an ifc module/header coming up.

> **/Tp** - Forces the compiler to recognize it as a C++ file, useful if renaming to `.cppm`.

> **/reference** - Tells the compiler where to get the dependency information for the following